# Read mesibo local db using Room Library

Tags: android, kotlin, mesibo

I'm using device explorer and find mesibo local database written using SQLite
[image]

It's possible to access that file using Room library rather than using mesibo SDK?, I want to make advance query and use livedata, coroutines etc, to reduce code complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is technically possible to access mesibo database directly, this is not the recommended or supported operation for a few reasons:

- Although the mesibo database structure is open, it is meant for mesibo's internal use only and subject to change without notice in future mesibo versions. Any code written to directly access the database would be prone to breaking with mesibo updates.
- Direct database access bypasses the mesibo SDK and cache, as well as the SDK's mechanisms for managing data consistency, synchronization, etc. This could lead to issues like data corruption.

If you have a specific need that the SDK does not address, please email us a feature request. We're happy to look into supporting your use case.